# seaborn violinplots: change violin color, axes names, legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I used to create all my plots using `matplotlib` until I recently discovered `seaborn`. I found particularly interesting the fact that it allows you to split violins in order to compare a given `hue` variable.

Well, my major problem is that I don't know what do I have to modify in order to change **violin colors**, **axes names**, or **place the legend** where I want.

Here is the example I followed from `seaborn`:

```
    import seaborn as sns
    tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
    sns.set(style="ticks", palette="colorblind")
    g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", size=4, aspect=.75)
    g = g.map(sns.violinplot, "sex", "total_bill", "smoker", inner=None, linewidth=1, scale="area", split=True, width=0.75).despine(left=True).add_legend(title="smoker")
    g.savefig(os.path.join(options.output_dir, "figures", "violinplots.png"))
```

And here is the output figure `violinplots.png`:

[image]

While I would rather like something like this:

[image]

To summarize:

- use `white` and `blue` colors
- replace axes `names`
- write `leftmost y axis` only
- make my own `legend with the blue category only`

Thank you in advance. Any help will be welcome.

---

In case anyone was interested, here is how I finally resolved the figure thanks to [MrPedru22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4299720/mrpedru22):

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.set(context="paper", palette="colorblind", style="ticks")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", sharey=False, size=4, aspect=.5)
g = g.map(seaborn.violinplot, "sex", "total_bill", "smoker", cut=0, inner=None, split=True, palette={"No": "#4477AA", "Yes": "white"}, saturation=1).despine(left=True)
# Set axis labels & ticks #
g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_xlabel("Lunch")
g.fig.get_axes()[1].set_xlabel("Dinner")
g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_xticklabels(["Male", "Female"])
g.fig.get_axes()[1].set_xticklabels(["Male", "Female"])
g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_ylabel("Total bill")
g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_yticks(range(0, 80, 10))
g.fig.get_axes()[1].set_yticks([])
g.fig.get_axes()[0].spines["left"].set_visible(True)
# Set legend #
handles, labels = g.fig.get_axes()[0].get_legend_handles_labels()
g.fig.get_axes()[0].legend([handles[1]], ["Non-smoker"], loc='upper left')
# Fixing titles #
g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_title("")
g.fig.get_axes()[1].set_title("")
g.plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Yes of course, I've been stacked on it for the whole weekend, that's why I'm asking.

For the violin colors: I have changed both color in the sns.violinplot, and the palette in sns.set() by my own palette of colors. When I create a color palette of two colors, it just ignores the second color. It uses the first color and a lighter version of that color. The same if I define color.

For the legend, in theory it should place the legend outside, but it's ignoring it.

The names and axis I could replace them with illustrator, so it's not such a big deal. But I'm really frustrated with the colors.

Comment: For instance, it's you who removes the axis with `despine(left=True)`. My guess is that you did not read the doc enough. If only the color matter, try reducing your question to only the color part, and show us what you try, then someone might answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are some answers:

```
import seaborn as sns
tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.set(style="ticks", palette="colorblind")
g = sns.FacetGrid(tips, col="time", size=4, aspect=.75)
g = g.map(sns.violinplot, "sex", "total_bill", "smoker", palette={"No": "b", "Yes": "w"}, inner=None, linewidth=1, scale="area", split=True, width=0.75).despine(left=True)
g.fig.get_axes()[0].legend(title= 'smoker',loc='upper left')
g.set_axis_labels('lunch','total bill')
sns.plt.show()
```

- Use white and blue colors: through pallete, as demonstrated above ("w" means white)
- Replace axes names: with `set_axis_labels` method
- The rest I could not find an answer but please check the documentation: 
  http://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html#seaborn.FacetGrid
  Hope it helps!

Comment: If I understand it correctly, both violin plots are under `g.fig`. So, for example, if I want to access any element in the leftmost violin plot that would be through the 0 ax (`g.fig.get_axes()[0]`), otherwise through the 1 ax (`g.fig.get_axes()[1]`), right?

Comment: Yes that's correct. So, as you wanted to replace sex by lunch and dinner, you can do it with `g.fig.get_axes()[0].set_xlabel("lunch")` and `g.fig.get_axes()[1].set_xlabel("dinner")`

Comment: Do you have any idea on how to join both x spines as if they were one single axis?