# How to use the `split` argument in a `seaborn.violinplot` in a `seaborn.FacetGrid`

Tags: python, seaborn

The quest is to make a [`FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) containing [`violinplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.violinplot.html)s with split violins.

Setup for a FacetGrid containing violinplots without split:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "value": np.random.rand(20),
        "condition": ["true", "false"]*10,
        "category": ["right"]*10 + ["wrong"]*10,
    }
)
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="category", hue="condition", col_wrap=5)
g.map(sns.violinplot, "value");
```

[image: A FacetGrid with violinplots.]

The following is a violin plot showing part of the data as a violinplot with a "split":

```py
p = sns.violinplot(
    data=df[df["category"]=="right"],
    x="value",
    y="category",
    hue="condition",
    split=True
)
```

[image]

Adding the split argument within the `map` doesn't produce the desired split plots. It is as if split is being ignored:

```py
g = sns.FacetGrid(data=df, col="category", hue="condition", col_wrap=5)
g.map(sns.violinplot, "value", split=True);
```

[image]

```py
sns.__version__ # '0.12.1'
```

Comment: There might be a hint in https://stackoverflow.com/q/33244836/6018688, but I couldn't figure it out how to replicate the behavior in the above example.

Comment: [sns.catplot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) can create a `FacetGrid` of violin plots. The docs page has an example of `sns.catplot(data=titanic, x="age", y="class", hue="sex", kind="violin", bw=.25, cut=0, split=True)`. It seems to need both `x=` and `y=`, unlike your example.

Comment: @JohanC Thank you for the investigation. I tried with and without the keywords and with x and y, without success.

Comment: Does `sns.catplot(data=titanic, x="age", y="class", hue="sex", kind="violin", bw=.25, cut=0, split=True)` work for you?  To use `x`, `y`, `hue` and `col` you need 4 different columns of your dataframe (your test example only has 3 columns).  Maybe you could add another example to clearly show what you mean by *"without success"*?

Comment: The exmple you gave does produce a plot: `sns.catplot(data=df, x="value", y="condition", hue="category", kind="violin", split=True)`, but it is still stacking the condition data in the `y` axis and I would like them  as columns. Is it impossible to use `col` and `hue` but only one of `x` or `y`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems seaborn doesn't allow `y` to be empty for these `catplot`s.  You can work around this by creating a dummy y value:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)
df = pd.DataFrame({"value": np.random.rand(20),
                   "condition": ["true", "false"] * 10,
                   "category": ["right"] * 10 + ["wrong"] * 10})
df["y"] = "" # create a dummy column to be used as "y="
sns.catplot(data=df, x="value", y="y", col="condition", hue="category", kind="violin", split=True)
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.catplot with dummy y]